# Sharing app-specific files and data between ios users

Tags: iphone

I am writing an app that allows users to create and save (locally) various visual models.  A new requirement has come up to allow users to share their models.

Has anyone had an experience doing this and what is the best way of implementing this?  Ideally I would like to be able to attach a file or a link to an email/tweet and then send it off and then it opens the file in the app or if you don't have the app installed it send you to the app in the app store?

**Update:**  The [MindJet](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mindjet-for-ipad/id440272860?mt=8) iPad app does exactly what I need

Comment: This article explains this in great detail: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make your own api on a http server so you can handle the data the users send. and when some one install your application you can check by making a function execute once the app launched if this user "also i suppose here that you have implement a registration module" have any shared data so you can download it ...

Answer (score 0):

The example app you name (mindjet) seems to be using dropbox for its file service.

http://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: Yes but how does it create its specific file types which open the app directly from an email

Comment: Did you check their developer pages? 
http://www.dropbox.com/developers 
;
http://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk (This page has a tutorial for iOS.) 

Can't help you with the details, never used it myself.